# php- curl is not working?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send POST requests to Digitalocean's API v2 with cURL and custom headers but it is not working. I don't get any response, or the output/response I get is only:

> Response from API:

My php code is:

```
<?php
$TOKEN = "digitalocean api token";

$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN","Content-Type: application/json",);

 $name = "Test"; //droplet name
 $region = "nyc2"; //region
 $size = "512mb"; //size
 $image = "303022"; //replace it
 $user_data = "#!/bin/bash apt-get install nginx -y";

$postData = array(
'name' => $name,
'region' => $region,
'size' => $size,
'image' => $image,
'user_data' => $user_data,);

$post_body = '';
foreach($postData as $key => $value) {
$post_body.= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}
$post_body = rtrim($post_body, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "Response from API: $result";
?>
```

Please tell me what's wrong in it? I have error reporting enabled.

Comment: Why aren't you simply passing the `$postData` array to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);`? No need to process it that way. You're also missing a `curl_close` call at the end, and you really should be passing the authentication stuff as CURL options, not in the headers array (see the manual for the options that allow you to do all this)

Comment: Don't try to encode the post data yourself.  Use PHP's built-in [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) function for that:  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));`

Comment: The api docs of digitalocean mentions to use headers for auth. and curl_close() isn't necessary

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Note that with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:  If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.

Comment: i tried that too; didnt work. :(

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Nips, you're right, but OP is formatting the array as if it were `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not json... so to the OP: check the data format, make sure it matches the format

Comment: Try to use `curl_error` to see what is says: `if($result === FALSE){ echo curl_error($ch); }`.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I didn't notice the `Content-Type: application/json` in the header.  That's probably the issue.

Comment: @AppfestiveReports: `curl_close` isn't the cause of the problem, but it is indicative of messy code, IMHO

Comment: @AppfestiveReports: Why do you have `Content-Type: application/json` in the header?  Is that what the API told you to do?  There is *no* JSON used anywhere in this code.  If they told you to use JSON, then you need to do: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));`  (P.S. In either case, get rid of your `$post_body` variable and the loop)

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat worked, pls make it an answer :)

Comment: @AppfestiveReports: I've already pointed the header issue out in my answer (and in one of the comments above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the `$headers` array more closely, I noticed you're sending your content as `application/json`, but at the same time, the postfields value does not match that content type. You'll probably have to add this:

```
$postFields = json_encode($postData);
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postFields));
//set your opts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);//json encoded string
```

If that doesn't work, add the result of

```
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

To your question, that'll tell you everything there is to know about the status of your curl request.

Comment: I don't know if `Content-Length` is really necessary.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I can guarantee you it isn't. I'm just a bit anal about some things, and setting length headers is just one of the things I tend to do.